# Customizing Qt Dock

Tags: c++, qt

What I'm looking to do is use the Qt Dock and the Dock widgets as they are, except I would like the show only the widget as opposed to the whole Dock.

to clarify: when a docked widget is brought into view, the whole dock appears and the widget sits on the dock. I would like to hide the portion of the dock which isn't being occupied by the widget, is there any way to do that?

Please let me know if I can clarify further.

Comment: Is hiding the Dock's frame what you ask?

Comment: well im not sure what that means...basically I want the dock functionality without showing the dock...only the dock widget

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is feasible with Dock widgets. There are 4 fixed dock areas on a QMainWindow which are shown if a dock widget is dropped onto them.

What you might try is to disable actual docking with `void setAllowedAreas(Qt::NoDockWidgetArea)` and handle "snapping" yourself with `void QWidget::moveEvent ( QMoveEvent * event )`, snapping the widget to the main window edges if it comes within x pixels of it.

Answer (score 0):

Hummm this seems difficult... 
For a start, use `QDockWidget::setTitleBarWidget ( QWidget * widget )` to set a custom title bar. You can create a special widget which has a small minimum size, minimum size hint, and which is not painted (or painted as invisible)...